# Размер окна браузера

Tags: c#

Запускаю браузер с помощью `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("www.google.com");` Принципиально именно таким способом, потому что использую некоторые расширения в процессе. Вопрос, как задать статичные размеры окна браузера? Знаю, что у встроенного браузера есть метод, отвечающий за размер окна.

Comment: Process.Start запускает браузер по умолчанию, он не может знать, что у браузера есть специальный метод. Если вам нужна тонкая настройка, запускайте конкретный .exe по имени и передавайте нужные параметры.

Comment: @VladD вы об этом говорили ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe");
            startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Minimized;

            Process.Start(startInfo);

            startInfo.Arguments = "www.northwindtraders.com";

            Process.Start(startInfo); ? как задать конкретный размер окна?

Comment: Ну, вы говорили, что у браузера есть метод, отвечающий за размеры окна. Какой это метод? Вот этим методом и нужно воспользоваться.

Comment: @VladD я имел ввиду, что такой метод есть у встроенного в vs браузера и у seleniuma.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как вариант, можно вот так:

```
 Process.Start("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe", "--window-size=800,600 --window-position=0,0  --app=\"http://www.google.com/\"");
```

Comment: Очень похоже на то, что я искал. Вопрос, возможно ли задать стартовое положение окна(допустим левый верхний угол).

Comment: @cruim Да. Отредактировал ответ.